# How do I implement IWebPartField.Schema correctly when providing a string field

Tags: c#, sharepoint

[The MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebpartfield.aspx) shows how to use a DataTable to find the propertydescriptor. A DataTable is overkill when all I need to do is store and forward a short string value.

One example looks somewhat sane, it's using TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["afieldnameintheclass"]. This looks correct to me.

The thing that's confusing me is that a similar example uses an attribute, [ConnectionProvider("Web part Connection Provider")], on the public IWebPartField GetWPConnectFieldProvider() function and seems to be referencing that in his GetProperties call (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["Web part Connection Provider"]).

Is the sane-seeming example correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd gone code-blind.

If the value you wanted to provide to a consumer web part was stored in the field:

```
string afieldnameintheclass;
```

You would use the following schema property.

```
public PropertyDescriptor Schema {
{
  get
  {
    return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["afieldnameintheclass"];
  }
}
```